# How can I share files from my Windows XP machine to my friend's Ubuntu 12.10 machine?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

How can I share files from my Windows XP machine to my friend's Ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on precisely what you want to do, you can just use standard "Windows Filesharing" and have your friend use a SMB Client to get the files, ie Ubuntu supports Windows Filesharing.

An alternative (particularly if you are not on the same LAN) might be to run a web server on your XP machine which points to the files you want to share.  This has the advantage of being easier to secure (and get working) across the Wider Internet as HTTP is a much simpler protocol.

There are also other options, like running an FTP server or finding an NFS server for XP (NFS is the Unix/Linux way of sharing files.   You do get Windows NFS clients - not that I've used them.  Have a look [HERE](http://www.networkedmediatank.com/showthread.php?tid=1434)).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not on the same network, and both have an Internet connection, using a free [Dropbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox_%28service%29) account would enable you and your friend to share files between each other. As a simpler alternative, you can copy to a USB drive; both Ubuntu and Windows can use this format without any hitches.